# Operator += for Double in java

Tags: java, double, operator-keyword

I have a syntax like this :

```
Double rowIDR += (((Double)view.getTableRaw().getModel().getValueAt(d,4)));
```

but the operator `+=` couldn't work , so what's operator that match with `Double` but have similar function like `+=` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to declare and assign something? Or are you trying to add something to `rowIDR`?

Comment: i want to call the list of table in coloumn rowIDR ..

Comment: You always can use simple assignment  rowIDR = rowIDR + *some big statement*

Comment: Don't use a `Double` when a `double` is more appropriate. Using `Double` with `+=` results in the creation of an Object every time which is not efficient.

Answer (score 4):

When you write following:

```
Double rowIDR += (((Double)view.getTableRaw().getModel().getValueAt(d,4)));
```

you are adding into `rowIDR` **without initializing it**.

Can you try this:

```
Double rowIDR = 0d; 
rowIDR+= (((Double)view.getTableRaw().getModel().getValueAt(d,4)));
```

Comment: what the function of '0d' in that declaration ?

Comment: It's just a way to represent [Floating point literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.2)

Comment: Double rowIDR = 0d; 
rowIDR+= view.getTableRaw().getModel().getValueAt(d,4);

when i use this, its caused error "cannot be cast" ..

Comment: Leave it; use `Double rowIDR = 0d; 
rowIDR+= (((Double)view.getTableRaw().getModel().getValueAt(d,4)));
`

Comment: actually i want to display the value in jasper report, when i use += in string, the data was displayed from first row until last row, but when i used it in double and big decimal , just last row that has been displayed ..

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `Double` here? Post another question for `jasper` report.

Comment: yes, because the type of data that i want to displayed is Double in program, but in jasper i've declared it in String

Comment: Please post another question; I think you need to concatenate instead of adding...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double a = 1.0;
    Double b = new Double(1.1), c;
    b += 1.1;
    c += 1.1;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

b is fine ,c is wrong.
because c is not initialized

Comment: -1, you should add more explanation instead of just "this is wrong"

Comment: because c is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Every local variable must be assigned begore use.So when we write

```
Int a+=3;
```

It's equivalent to-:

```
Int a=a+3;
```

So you are using the local variable a without initializing  it.So if you write like this

```
Int a=0;
a+=3;
```

It will work.

Comment: A couple of things... **First** `Int` is not a keyword. **Second** `a+=3;` is equivalent to `a=(int)(a+3);`

Answer (score -2):

Actually this should work. Maybe you did something wrong like the value on the right hand side is "0". ;)

edit: didn't see the initilization. This vould be the prob as well.